# Mockito spies - verify() calls the method instead of checking

Tags: spring, mockito, springockito

I'm trying to use Springockito and spies to verify that calls were made/not made on a service method during an end-to-end test. I'm autowiring the service that the process will also get, and spy on it. Although myService instance is instrumented, verify() does not verify previous calls, but makes a call to the original method and passes a null parameter. Why is this?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = PatchedSpringockitoContextLoader.class, locations = {
    "classpath:/config.xml"
})
...
@Autowired
@WrapWithSpy
private MyService myService;
...
@Before
public void setup() {
    initMocks(this);
    ...
}
...
@Test
public void test() {
    // run the process that may or may not call the service
    verify(myService, never()).myMethod(any(MyParam.class));
}
```

Comment: Is `myMethod` declared `static` or `final` ?

Comment: No, regular public instance method.

Comment: How about MyService? Is it `public` and non-`final`?

Comment: public @Service class, not final.

Comment: Any chance we could get a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? I'm very curious about this myself

Comment: It can be connected with that that instead of spy you are getting some proxy object because you are using some aspects, but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

What might be happening here is that your spied object uses annotations (e.g `@Transactional`) that requires Spring to add an AOP proxy around your spy, which causes Mockito to malfunction.

I've had the same issue as yours although I do not use Spock, and I solved it by getting a reference to the proxied mock or spy from the Spring proxy.

Check out the suggested hack in this [GitHub issue report](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6828).

I am not using Spring Boot, so I wrapped the workaround code in a `@BeforeClass` method.

Comment: I did have this issue with Spring Retry (@Retryable annotations).