# Unit Testing a class with ServiceLocatorFactoryBean Autowired

Tags: spring, junit, mockito, springmockito

I have a Interface which is registered as part of ServiceLocatorFactoryBean. The main purpose of this Interface is to act as a factory.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ServiceLocatorFactoryBean.html

I have "autowired" this Interface in various classes, that I want to test now with Mockito.

The issue is Mockito doesn't support interfaces. How can inject a mock of this interface in the class I am testing.

The only alternative I see is to run the test using SpringJunitRunner and providing an Application Context which has the bean configurations. But this is too verbose.

Comment: What do you mean by "Mockito does not support interfaces"? It totally does :)  
  
What is the issue with this for example:  
`MyInterface myInterface = Mockito.mock(MyInterface.class);`  
  
You can then set this when you create the class you want to test.

Comment: A small correction in the above question, I am trying to @spy on the interface rather than mock it. The issue is that I do not have concrete implementation of the class for that interface. if you look at the ServiceLocatorFactoryBean link I have posted above, the documentation mentions that you just create an interface and let it be, and spring provides run time implementation of the interface. But, spy cannot work with interface.  This is from Mockito.spy documentation " But Mockito cannot instantiate inner classes, local classes, abstract classes and interfaces."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it you'd like to spy on the implementation that Spring generated for your interface?! That's close to impossible to achieve with what you have so far... However there are at least the following alternatives below.

Suppose we have the following setup:

```java
public interface MyService {
    String doIt();
}
```

```java
@Component
public static class ServiceConsumer {
    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    public String execute() {
        return service.doIt();
    }
}
```

---

**0) Later edit:** while [roaming around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158738/mockito-spies-verify-calls-the-method-instead-of-checking), I found that it may be possible to spy and even replace an autowired field with a mock, and fairly easy too, using [Springockito-annotations](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/springockito-annotations).

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ComponentScan
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringockitoAnnotatedContextLoader.class, classes = {SpringockitoConsumerTest.class})
public class SpringockitoConsumerTest {

    @WrapWithSpy(beanName = "myService")
    @Autowired
    private MyService mockService;

    @Autowired
    private ServiceConsumer consumer;

    @Test
    public void shouldConsumeService() {
        assertEquals("allDone", consumer.execute());
        verify(mockService).doIt();
    }
}
```

*If `Springockito-annotations` is out of the question, please see the 2 original suggestions below*

---

**1)** You could just create your mock of the interface and auto-inject it Mockito in your bean. This is the simplest solution (I could think of at the time of writing) but it does not ensure that the `@Autowired` annotation was not forgotten in the consumer (perhaps a dedicated test could be added?!):

```java
public class AutoInjectMocksConsumerTest {

    @Mock
    private MyService serviceMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private ServiceConsumer consumer = new ServiceConsumer();

    @Before
    public void initMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        when(serviceMock.doIt()).thenReturn("allDone");
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldConsumeService() {
        assertEquals("allDone", consumer.execute());
        verify(serviceMock).doIt();
    }
}
```

---

**2)**  Alternatively as you also said, you could run it with the `SpringJunitRunner` making a minimum of effort to define and instantiate the necessary Spring context while also providing your own service mock. Albeit people may complain this solution *is not that clean*, I find it sufficiently elegant and it also validates that the `@Autowired` annotation was not forgotten in the consumer implementation.

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringAutowiringConsumerTest.class})
public class SpringAutowiringConsumerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService mockService;

    @Autowired
    private ServiceConsumer consumer;

    @Test
    public void shouldConsumeService() {
        assertEquals("allDone", consumer.execute());
        verify(mockService).doIt();
    }

    @Bean
    public MyService mockService() {
        MyService serviceMock = mock(MyService.class);
        when(serviceMock.doIt()).thenReturn("allDone");
        return serviceMock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments @Morfic. Very useful.